# Codeigniter: Show the form validation errors in tooltip format

Tags: php, tooltip, codeigniter-3

I am using simple registration form for my site. Where I want to show the errors in tooltip format.Is It possible?

I have tried some of the solutions, but its not working.

```
$(function () {
$('input[name=name]').tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    container:'#nameDiv',
    title: '<?php echo $error_title;?>',
    /*trigger: "hover"*/
}).tooltip('show');
});
```

Comment: Using jquery or javscript? Show us your demo please

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of Jquery Validation Engine?

Let's try it:

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: what if someone disabled javascript, that's why I want to make it server-side check and then display into tooltip although if javascript is disabled user cant go further cause server-side checking is happening

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do:

```
<form id="messageForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email address</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#messageForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            message: {
                // The messages for this field are shown as usual
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The message is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 20,
                        max: 500,
                        message: 'The message must be more than 20 and less than 500 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                // Show the message in a tooltip
                err: 'tooltip',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The email address is not valid'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Reference Link :
[Using Bootstrap](http://formvalidation.io/examples/using-tooltip-to-show-message/)

The above example is using Bootstrap, you can even do that using Jquery/Javascript.